# Selecting head records with only the first occurring line record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables. SHead & SLine

SHead

```
id - title - origin - Status - datetime
```

SLine

```
id - sid - datetime - body
```

I want to select all records from SHead where origin = 4. I want only the first recorded row from SLine though.

So if I have one row in SHead for origin=4 and two related rows in SLine, I only want to return one row. Is this possible?

Comment: the first mean the lowest id, isnt?

Comment: show us sample data and expected output. Also help you show us what have you try. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a typical way:

```
select h.*, l.*
from shead h join
     sline l
     on l.sid = h.id
where s.original = 4 and
      l.datetime = (select min(l2.datetime) from sline l2 where l2.sid = l.sid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT sh.*,
       s1.*
FROM   SLine s1
       JOIN (SELECT Min(datetime) min_dt,
                    sid
             FROM   SLine
             GROUP  BY sid) s2
         ON s2.min_dt = s1.datetime
            AND s2.sid = s1.sid
       JOIN SHead sh
         ON sh.id = s1.sid
```